# How do I construct a inverse join for a unidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, jpa, join, eclipselink, criteria-api

I guess this is easy, but I can't figure it out.

If I have entities Foo and Bar:

```
@Entity
class Foo{
   @OneToMany
   List<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
class Bar{
   @Column
   int data;
}
```

and if I want to create a Join (`javax.persistence.criteria.Join<Foo, Bar>`) object, I can do it like this:

```
Root<Foo> root = ...;
Join<Foo,Bar> join = root.join(Foo_.bars);
```

But how can I make an inverse join

```
Join<Bar,Foo> inverseJoin = barRoot.join....()...?
```

since I don't have a java field in the class Bar that points to it's Foo parent, it is unidirectional relation?

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is: it isn't a unidirectional relationship if you need an inverse join. Have you checked out using a bidirectional relation (adding `@ManyToOne` to `Bar`)?

Comment: I've considered that, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You can probably need to resort to a raw SQL query, then. I don't know of way to do what you want and IMHO there shouldn't be one.

Comment: Check this answer... Maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939173/criteria-query-for-unidirectional-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score -1):

If what you need is given a known Bar who is its belonging Foo this would fit. Sentence will not be translated to a SQL JOIN but it is semantically equivalent.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);

Root<Foo> fooRoot = cq.from(Foo.class);
Root<Bar> barRoot = cq.from(Bar.class);

cq.select(fooRoot);
cq.where(barRoot.in(fooRoot.get("bars")));
```

Comment: **barRoot.in**
I wonder if it works with **equal** instead of **in**

Comment: **fooRoot.get("bars")** is a collection. Using **equal** would try to compare a single element (**barRoot**) to a collection, which is wrong.

Comment: Won't this create a cartesian product (cross-join, i.e. performance hell)?

Comment: It all depends on your indexes. If the foreign key column on Bar and the primary key on Foo are indexed (PK always are but FK depends on your database) the performance of the query shouldn't be much worse than a join.

Comment: This solution is not working (at least for me with Hibernate 5.2.11). I have to replace where clause from `barRoot.in(fooRoot.get("bars"))` to `barRoot.in(fooRoot.joinList("bars"))`. However it generates very suboptimal query with one cross join and two inner joins. For simpler solution without two root objects check answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939173