# Criteria query for unidirectional one-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, criteria-api

So, I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Supplier {
    @Column(name = "SUPPLIERID")
    private BigInteger supplierId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SUPP", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_POIS_SUPP"))
    private List<POS> posList;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class POS {
    @Column(name = "POSID")
    private BigInteger posId
}
```

So, `POS` does not have a reference to `Supplier`, which means that we have a unidirectional one-to-many relationship. I need to look for a `POS` by `posId` and `supplierId`. That is, find a supplier with the specified `supplierId` and then find a pos in the supplier's list of pos's that has the specified posId. How do I write a criteria query for this?

I tried using subqueries. My idea was to create a subquery that would fetch all `POS`'s of a `Supplier` with a given `supplierId`. Then the main query would search within those `POS`'s for a `POS` with the given `posId`.

The problem was I couldn't write a query that would fetch a `Supplier`s list of `POS`s. Apparently you can't write a query of type `List<POS>`:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<POS> outerQuery = cb.createQuery(POS.class);
Root<POS> outerQueryRoot = outerQuery.from(POS.class);

Subquery<POS> subquery = outerQuery.subquery(POS.class);
Root<Supplier> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(Supplier.class);
subquery.where(cb.equal(subqueryRoot.get(Supplier_.supplierId), supplierId));
subquery.select(subqueryRoot.get(Supplier_.posList);
```

On this last line, I get a compilation error that `Expression<POS> does not match Expression<List<POS>>`. And I can't change the type of the subquery because Java doesn't allow generic class literals (`List<POS>.class`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer, just use two `roots`:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<POS> cq = cb.createQuery(POS.class);

    Root<POS> posRoot = cq.from(POS.class);
    Root<Supplier> supplierRoot = cq.from(Supplier.class);

    cq.where(cb.and(
                    cb.equal(supplierRoot.get(Supplier_.suppliertId), supplierId),
                    cb.equal(posRoot.get(POS_.posId), posId)));
    cq.select(posRoot);
```

Comment: To be careful, with what you are doing here, Hibernate do a **cross join**, I have expected something else. For me your solution doesn't works well. -1

Answer (score 7):

I found very simple solution without subquery. Start from Suppler, join POS through posList and then 'select' POS.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<POS> query = cb.createQuery(POS.class);

Root<Supplier> supplierRoot = query.from(Supplier.class);
ListJoin<Supplier, POS> posList = supplierRoot.joinList(Supplier_.posList);
query
    .select(posList)
    .where(
        cb.equal(supplierRoot.get(Supplier_.suppliertId), supplierId),
        cb.equal(posList.get(POS_.posId), posId)
    );
```

With Hibernate 5.2.11 it generated nice query with two inner joins through N->M table very similar to manually written code ;-).
Accepted answer is I guess wrong because it skips "posList" relation. It will select POS objects which are not in relation with specified Supplier.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the newer and most useful generation of hibernate.

Comment: How are you even able to do a select on "posList"? "posList" is a ListJoin and "select" expects a Selection...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with subqueries. SQL equivalent to the jpql "select p from POS p where p.id in (select sp.id from Supplier s join s.posList sp where s.id = :supplierId)"

See [JPA2 Criteria-API: select... in (select from where)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854334/jpa2-criteria-api-select-in-select-from-where/10858479#10858479)

Comment: I was unable to test if this works because I don't have experience with criteria queries. Perhaps someone who is more versed in the subject could help.

Comment: Did you follow the link? It has an example.

Comment: I read the link. But I couldn't write the subquery, it wouldn't compile. I'll elaborate in the question itself.