# Criteria query for many-to-one unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939173/criteria-query-for-unidirectional-one-to-many-relationship) answers the opposite relationship. I have been trying to come up with a Criteria Query for the following model:

```
@Entity
public class One {

    @Id
    private BigInteger supplierId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;


    ...
}

@Entity
public class Many {

    @Id
    private BigInteger posId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "column_name")
    One one;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;
}
```

I cannot change the model. I most keep it unidirectional in that way. I am trying to come up with the Criteria Builder code for the following situation:
-I will be given the following attributes: `nam`, `desc`.  I need to find all the `One` entities whose name attribute is equal to `nam`, and that have a related `Many` entity whose description attribute is equal to `desc`

Answer (score -2):

```
Criteria query = this.getSession().createCriteria(Many.class);
query = query.add(Restrictions.eq("one.name", nam));
query = query.add(Restrictions.eq("description", desc));
query.list();
```

This way doesn't work??

Comment: I will translate it to the JPA criteria builder and check if it works. But I have my suspicion it won't. I think that I need two roots to make it work, and a join.

Comment: Also note that I am looking for the results to be of the type `One`

Comment: just get the value with may.getOne() or it's set as eager? You can use a subquery too in criteria...